# sed regular expression to replace value with variable of same name

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk, sed

I am trying to replace a some variables in a yml file.

Samepl.yml

```
spring:
  metadataMap:
    instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${randomvalue}
client:
  version: 1.0
  myval: {{ myVal }}
```

I am using following command to replace all the values inside double braces eg: {{ var }}  with a environment variable of same name i.e value of: ${var} it should fail if variable is undefined. But no luck

```
cat sample.yml | sed -e "s/{{ \(.*\) }}/${\1:?}/g" > /tmp/a
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: When the shell expands the string inside the double quotes to send to sed, it can't know what sed is going to resolve `\1` to.

Comment: Use a proper templating tool, not `sed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Perl for that:

```
perl -pE 's:{{\s*(\S+?)\s*}}:$ENV{$1} // die "$1 not set":ge'
```

If your Perl is older than 5.10, you need to be more verbose:

```
perl -pe 's%{{\s*(\S+?)\s*}}%exists $ENV{$1} ? $ENV{$1} : die "$1 not set"%ge'
```

Comment: Hi @choroba,  is there any fix for following pattern.. 
 ` {{var1}}:{{var2}}/{{var3}}`

Its not matching individual  vars

Comment: @Pasha: Updated: `?` added after `+` to make the match frugal.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ myVal="foo" gawk 'match($0,/(.*{{\s*)(\S+)(\s*}}.*)/,a) && (a[2] in ENVIRON) { $0 = a[1] ENVIRON[a[2]] a[3] } 1' file
spring:
  metadataMap:
    instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${randomvalue}
client:
  version: 1.0
  myval: {{ foo }}

$ other="foo" gawk 'match($0,/(.*{{\s*)(\S+)(\s*}}.*)/,a) && (a[2] in ENVIRON) { $0 = a[1] ENVIRON[a[2]] a[3] } 1' file
spring:
  metadataMap:
    instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${randomvalue}
client:
  version: 1.0
  myval: {{ myVal }}
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ myVal="foo" gawk 'match($0,/(.*{{\s*)(\S+)(\s*}}.*)/,a) { if (a[2] in ENVIRON) { $0 = a[1] ENVIRON[a[2]] a[3]} else {print "the sky is falling!"; exit} } 1' file
spring:
  metadataMap:
    instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${randomvalue}
client:
  version: 1.0
  myval: {{ foo }}

$ other="foo" gawk 'match($0,/(.*{{\s*)(\S+)(\s*}}.*)/,a) { if (a[2] in ENVIRON) { $0 = a[1] ENVIRON[a[2]] a[3]} else {print "the sky is falling!"; exit} } 1' file
spring:
  metadataMap:
    instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${randomvalue}
client:
  version: 1.0
the sky is falling!
```